# Getting string length for morse code convertor keeps looping

Tags: c++, morse-code

working on one of my first programming assignments, a text to morse (and back) convertor, but for whatever reason when I introduce a piece of text with a space between words my programme goes into an endless loop and crashes. Any ideas? Sorry if this description sucks, still getting my head around programming lingo.

this is the piece of the program that isn't functioning properly:

```
    {

        string user_input;
        cout << "----------------------------------------" <<endl
        << "Text to Morse Mode" << endl
        << "Enter text for conversion : "<<endl;
        cin >> user_input;
        cout << endl << endl << user_input << " converts to : ";
        unsigned int str_lenght;
        str_lenght=user_input.size();
        cout << endl;

        for (i=0;i<str_lenght;i++)
        {

            find_string=0;

            while (find_string < stop_string)
            {


                if (user_input[i]==text[find_string][0])
                {
                    count=1;
                    cout << morse[find_string] << " ";
                    break;


                }

                find_string = find_string+1;
            }

        }

        cout << endl << endl << endl;

        if (count==0)
            cout << endl << " an error was encountered " << "\a" << endl ;
    }
```

Comment: So there are two approaches you can use, and you should learn both: (1) "printf debugging" means outputing the values of variables at various points in your program, and then running it to see what variables have what values over time. (2) "using a debugger" means using a program called a debugger that will run your program in a sandbox and allow you to stop it at various points and you can inspect whatever variables you want.  If you tell us what plaform you are using we can tell you the most common debugger that is used.

Answer (score 0):

`stop_string` isn't defined anywhere from what I see. In order to break the loop via incrementing you need to define `stop_string`. Also `find_string = find_string+1;` could be shortened to `find_string++`

Answer (score 0):

First you haven't defined stop_string variable anywhere. First define it or use another variable. If it is string length intent to use here, use the str_length you have created. 
Secondly if you want to input spaces in between your words, use getline instead of cin. cin delimits space character.